# How to check the presence of a given numpy array in a larger-shape numpy array?

Tags: numpy

I guess the title of my question might not be very clear..

I have a small array, say `a = ([[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,1]])`. Then I have a bigger array of a higher dimension, say `b = ([[[2,2,2],[2,0,1],[2,1,1]],[[0,0,0],[3,3,1],[3,1,1]],[...]])`.

I'd like to check if one of the elements of a can be found in `b`. In this case, I'd find that the first element of a `[0,0,0]` is indeed in `b`, and then I'd like to retrieve the corresponding index in `b`.

I'd like to do that avoiding looping, since from the very little I understood from numpy arrays, they are not meant to be iterated over in a classic way. In other words, I need it to be very fast, because my actual arrays are quite big.

Any idea?
Thanks a lot!

Arnaud.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a direct way, but I here's a function that works around the problem:

```
import numpy as np

def find_indices(val, arr):
    # first take a mean at the lowest level of each array,
    # then compare these to eliminate the majority of entries
    mb = np.mean(arr, axis=2); ma = np.mean(val)
    Y = np.argwhere(mb==ma)
    indices = []
    # Then run a quick loop on the remaining elements to
    # eliminate arrays that don't match the order
    for i in range(len(Y)):
        idx = (Y[i,0],Y[i,1])
        if np.array_equal(val, arr[idx]):
            indices.append(idx)

    return indices

# Sample arrays
a = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,1]])
b = np.array([ [[6,5,4],[0,0,1],[2,3,3]],   \
               [[2,5,4],[6,5,4],[0,0,0]],   \
               [[2,0,2],[3,5,4],[5,4,6]],   \
               [[6,5,4],[0,0,0],[2,5,3]]  ])



print(find_indices(a[0], b))
# [(1, 2), (3, 1)]
print(find_indices(a[1], b))
# [(0, 1)]
```

The idea is to use the mean of each array and compare this with the mean of the input. `np.argwhere()` is the key here. That way you remove most of the unwanted matches, but I did need to use a loop on the remainder to avoid the unsorted matches (this shouldn't be too memory-consuming). You'll probably want to customise it further, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Indeed such kind of workaround is a help!